# I'm trying to transfer data from one tab to another, but can't get it to paste

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet where I am entering data on a tab titled "Site Info".  I am trying to write a macro that will transfer that data to a second tab titled "Quotes" and then erase the data I entered on the "Site Info" tab.  The erase macro portion seems to be working, but it's not writing to the "Quotes" tab.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Example Data Entry Info on "Site Info" tab:
https://ibb.co/qybjJzF

Example of where data should past on "Quotes" tab:
https://ibb.co/V9JK50v

```
//Submit button
function Submit() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var formSht = ss.getSheetByName("Site Info");
var recordsSht = ss.getSheetByName("Quotes");

if ('F5'!="-"){
var data =
\[\[ formSht.getRange("B5").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B6").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B7").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B8").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B9").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B10").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B11").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B12").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B13").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B14").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B15").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("F5").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("G5").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("H5").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("I5").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("J5").getValue(), \]\];

recordsSht.getRange(recordsSht.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 16).setValues(data);

}
if ('F6'!="-") {
var data =
\[\[ formSht.getRange("B5").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B6").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B7").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B8").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B9").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B10").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B11").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B12").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B13").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B14").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B15").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("F6").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("G6").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("H6").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("I6").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("J6").getValue(), \]\];

recordsSht.getRange(recordsSht.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 16).setValues(data);

}
if ('F7'!="-"){
var data =
\[\[ formSht.getRange("B5").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B6").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B7").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B8").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B9").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B10").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B11").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B12").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B13").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B14").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("B15").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("F7").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("G7").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("H7").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("I7").getValue(),
formSht.getRange("J7").getValue(), \]\];

recordsSht.getRange(recordsSht.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 16).setValues(data);  

}`
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Are your sample images the sample input situations? If my understanding is correct, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample output situation you expect?

Comment: I couldn't get the images to load, so I added links you can go to where I've hosted them.  Hopefully that should clarify what I'm trying to do.  Thanks.